# strcmp is not working while doing socket I/O

Tags: c, sockets, strcmp

I am working on a simple socket based echo application. My client code is as below. Socket I/O is working flawlessly. I am getting echo back for every sent string. But I want to terminate the client when the user input is "exit". I have used strcmp() function to compare string. It doesn't seem to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main(int argc,char **argv){

    int sc,cli,b,tmp,clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serveradd;

    int port;
    char buffer[1024],sbuffer[1024];

    port = atoi(argv[2]);

    sc = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    memset(&serveradd,0,sizeof(serveradd));

    serveradd.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serveradd.sin_port=htons(port);
    serveradd.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);

    connect(sc, (struct sockaddr *) &serveradd, sizeof(serveradd));

    while(1){
        memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        scanf("%s",buffer);

        if(strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0){
            break;
        }

        send(sc, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
        memset(&sbuffer,0,sizeof(sbuffer));
        tmp=recv(sc,sbuffer,1023,0);
        sbuffer[tmp]='\0';
        printf("%s\n",sbuffer);
    }
        close(cli);




}
```

Comment: I am comparing the input directly after scanf(). I am not comparing the received string from server.

Answer (score 0):

`memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));`

Here it shouldn't be `&buffer` where you are trying to set address of buffer to zero. `buffer` itself is the base address.

Answer (score 0):

With `close(cli);`, `cli` is not initialized.  Thus UB.

As this is called after `strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0` is true, failure *appears* to be due to `strcmp()`.